# Wicket Modal Windows empty if behind Proxy

Tags: proxy, wicket

Hi all you genius people!

Has anybody ever had a problem with modal window's content when using the web site from behind a proxy? Sadly I cannot provide any details about the proxy configuration. (It's the proxy of a foreign company.)

I can tell you though that it is a Squid proxy and that there are no explicit error's in Wicket's ajax debug windows or the server log. Proxy admin also says there's nothing blockek in the logs. Wicket actually returns an empty div to be displayed in the modal window's content:

```
<div id="contentd" style="display:none"></div>
```

This is what is returned when I do not have the proxy between me and wicket:

```
<div id="content10">
  <form>
      <table align="center" cellspacing="5px" width="100%">
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center">
                  <span><p>Möchten Sie den Monitor wirklich löschen?</p></span>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td align="center">
                  <input type="button" value="Ok" class="button" id="confirm15" onclick="var wcall=wicketAjaxGet('?wicket:interface=:1:uniModal:content:confirm::IBehaviorListener:0:-1',function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('confirm15') != null;}.bind(this));return !wcall;">
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                  <input type="button" value="Abbrechen" class="button" id="confirmNot16" onclick="var wcall=wicketAjaxGet('?wicket:interface=:1:uniModal:content:confirmNot::IBehaviorListener:0:-1',function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('confirmNot16') != null;}.bind(this));return !wcall;">
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

(Sry for this horribly dirty html code, not a work of mine. ^^)

My guess is that the proxy captures parameter's that should arrive at wicket but never do. I switched on DEBUG for org.apache.wicket but can't find anything that might seem useful. Does anybody know an instant solution or have any ideas how to look into this further? After DEBUG logging showed nothing I pretty much ran out of ideas.

Maybe someone can read something out of the wicket logs:

- Working without proxy - http://pastebin.com/Agi2JMJM
- Not working with proxy - http://pastebin.com/hfzXDHtq

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<div id="contentd" style="display:none"></div>` is what Wicket outputs when you have a component that is not visible, but has the outputMarkupPlaceholderTag flag set to true. Check your visibility logic and see whether it's working correctly.

Comment: @Carl-EricMenzel Thanks for the reply, that is nice to know. As I said it works flawlessly when there's no proxy between me and wicket, so no chance the visibility settings might be wrong. But that brought up another idea. Checking that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution was quite easy, now that I know the details. Wicket uses two custom headers when handling modal windows:

- wicket-ajax
- wicket-focusedelementid

Without these headers wicket seems to be unable to identify the correct modal frame object or similar. The company's proxy server blocked  all non-whitelisted headers. After tweaking the proxy server to allow the headers above everything worked like a charm.